# What is the difference between spark checkpoint and local checkpoint?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-checkpoint

What is the difference between spark checkpoint and local checkpoint? When making local checkpoint I see this in the spark UI:

[image]

It shows that local checkpoint is saved on memory.

Comment: Where do you see "local checkpoint"?

Comment: In the image, this storage are relationed with the operations. In the code I use:

df.localCheckpoint()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Local checkpoint stores your data in executors storage (as shown in your screenshot).
It is useful for truncating the lineage graph of an RDD, however, in case of node failure you will lose the data and you need to recompute it (depending on your application you may have to pay a high price).

'Standard' checkpoint stores your data in a reliable file system (like hdfs). It is more expensive to perform but you will not need to recompute the data even in case of failures. Of course, it truncates the lineage graph.

Truncating a long lineage graph avoid getting stack overflow exceptions and is particularly useful in iterative [algorithms](https://www.webagesolutions.com/blog/archives/1608)

Comment: For me local checkpointing write directly to executors *disks*, not memory. The [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) says: "Local checkpoints are written to executor storage"

Answer (score 4):

- *local checkpointing* writes data in executors storage
- *regular checkpointing* writes data in HDFS

*local checkpointing* is faster than *classic checkpointing* but *regular checkpointing* is safer in that it leverages *HDFS* reliability (e.g. data blocks replication).